# Using external template with Mojolicious::Lite

Tags: perl, templates, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

trying to use the `HTMLTemplateProRenderer` plugin for
[`Mojolicious::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Lite)
so that I can use template files in the style of `HTML::Template`.

The issue is that every example, even documentation, only shows the template file attached to the script. I need the template file to be in a different directory from the Perl code.

Here is a sample of what I am trying to do.

This works using `__DATA__`, but how could it work by using an external template file as this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Mojolicious::Lite;

plugin 'HTMLTemplateProRenderer';

# Route leading to an action that renders a template
get '/test' => sub {
    my $c = shift;

    $c->stash( one => 'This is result one' );

    $c->render(
        template => 'display/index',
        two      => 'this is the second',
        handler  => 'tmpl'
    );
};

app->start;
```

The template file is `display/index.tmpl`

```
 <html>
  <head><title>Test Template</title>
   <body>
     <p>Value ONE =  <TMPL_VAR NAME="one"> </p>
     <p>Value TWO =  <TMPL_VAR NAME="two"> </p>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What happens if you run this?

Comment: Also there's a typo, you are missing a `'`.

Comment: bad arguments: expected filename or scalarref at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/HTML/Template/Pro.pm line 198. But how? Thats what I cant figured it out.

Comment: Did you try adding the file extension?

Comment: as this? $c->render(template => 'display/index', format => 'tmpl', handler  => 'tmpl'); - Yes, didn't work!

Comment: No, I meant in the `template`. Try `display/index.tmpl`.

Comment: That wouldn't make any difference, I tried before, Mojolicious::Lite, takes care of it without the extension, the module I am trying to use is where the issue is "HTMLTemplateProRenderer" I will contact the author since the documentation doesn't show any sample on how to do it like that.

Answer (score 1):

First, the template path must be in the format `<name>.<format>.<handler>`. So for `display/index` is `display/index.html.tmpl`.

Second, a template search paths for `HTMLTemplateProRenderer` are `templates` and `templates/<controller>` relative to app home. And app home if used plugin config option `tmpl_opts => {use_home_template => 1}`. Or any path added to `app->renderer->paths`.